# Spambot registration on Magento 2 website

Tags: magento2, php

my magento 2.2.3 website is over run by spam bots. the registration of fake users are through the roof and i need to have these stopped immediately.

I have google recaptcha and email verification for every account opened but yet there are still lots of intrusion to my registration with lots of fake email registration...
 any suggestions on what to do?

Comment: Could it be the API? So bypassing capcha. Trouble is you cant disable API as checkout won't work. If you can check your access logs. You may be able to block a handful of IPs. Not a permanent solution though.

Comment: Thanks but i am not seeing anything in the log..

can you specify the one you have in mind and path

Comment: Depends on stack. Examples https://www.keycdn.com/support/apache-access-log or perhaps https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/can-someone-tell-me-the-location-of-access-log-for-nginx but exact location differs. I work a lot on cpanel servers and should be a sym link in user directory